# Rails 3.1 Backbone JST in View will not compile with events

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, coffeescript

Working with the rails 3.1 asset pipeline and coffeescript.
I've used the rails-backbone gem for some generation to help me along and everything has been working well for me until I tried to put events to my view. As soon as I put anything to the events attribute the JST does not render (it does without it):

```
Headspace.Views.Shows ||= {}                                                                                                                              

class Headspace.Views.Shows.IndexView extends Backbone.View                                                                                               
  template: JST["backbone/templates/shows/index"]                                                                                                         

  el: '#show_listing'                                                                                                                                     

  initialize: () ->                                                                                                                                       
    @collection = @options.collection                                                                                                                     
    this.render()                                                                                                                                         

  events:                                                                                                                                                 
    'click .show_header' : 'show_details'                                                                                                                

  show_details = ()->                                                                                                                                     
    alert('action')                                                                                                                                       

  render: ->                                                                                                                                              
    $(@el).html(@template({collection:@collection}))
```

I've also tried an empty events attribute (which doesn't compile unless I put in the empty {}) which does render the JST. I've considered that el is defined as a string instead of a jQuery element (with $()) until the render function.  If I do specify:

```
el: $('#show_listing')
```

and:

```
render: ->
  el.html(@template({collection:@collection}))
```

The JST does not compile.

Comment: When you say the JST doesn't compile you mean you get an error on the server or on the client? What is the error?

Comment: That has been a source of frustration working with jst. There is no error, it just doesn't render.  I use the ejs gem to process the templates, though I don't get any errors anywhere (not even in firebug). It just doesn't render.

Comment: guess I shouldn't say it doesn't compile, everything gets processesed fine, just not rendered.  The "compiled" or processed JST is output fine in firebug.

Comment: Never worked with EJS but the readme says:
EJS.compile("Hello <%= name %>")
# => "function(obj){...}"

Not really what I see in you snippet..?

Nevermind if the output is ok

Comment: Yeah, you can put the template in a file or inline like in that example. The view renders if I don't have that events in there.

Comment: I did just put an alert in the render and ran it through chrome (firebug still has no error).  Its breaking on the events call:if (!method) throw new Error('Event "' + events[key] + '" does not exist');  Its as though it won't process the event because it thinks that a div (the item with .show_header is a div) is not clickable...

Answer (score 4):

just a mere typo you got there

instead of

```
 show_details = ()->                                                                                                                                     
    alert('action')
```

it is

```
  show_details : ()->                                                                                                                                     
    alert('action')
```

I am guessing you used shift+enter in textmate for the functions snippet? I have done that, too.